# require footer and header each page but error 500

Tags: php, require

**Hi**,

I start in PHP and I create my website. I create a component of header and footer to print on each page with : `require '/assets/components/header.php';` and `require '/assets/components/footer.php';`

So, the problem is that on localhost, it works, but on website, it didn't work and i have a http error 500

**Repertory :**
[Folder tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2tGF.png)

**I try :**

**1.** The different type of link

`require 'assets/components/header.php';`

`require './assets/components/header.php';`

`require '../assets/components/header.php';`

---

**2.** create a variable $BASE_URL to stock the url of the website and require like this : `require "$BASE_URL/assets/components/header.php";`. I set the setting 'allow_url_include' to true but i have this error :

```
[04-Nov-2021 12:28:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  require(http://#####/assets/components/header.php): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
```

'#####' -> my website

I read in a topic, that not secure to set 'allow_url_include' to true so if we can do different.

**Header.php**

```
<?php
require_once "$BASE_URL"."assets/function.php";
if(!isset($title)){
    $title='Error 404 - Catif';
}
if(!isset($page)){
    $page='error';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/assets/css/style.css'>
    <title><?= $title ?></title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-left"><p class="nav-name">Catif</p></div>
        <div class="nav-right">
            <a class="nav-item <?php if($page === 'home'): ?>active<?php endif ?>" href="/index.php">Projets</a>
            <a class="nav-item ml-80 <?php if($page === 'me'): ?>active<?php endif ?>" href="views/me.php">Moi</a>
            <a class="nav-item ml-80 <?php if($page === 'contact'): ?>active<?php endif ?>" href="/views/contact.php">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <button class="nav-button">==</button>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
```

Comment: share the content of header.php file

Comment: require works with the path, not the url

Comment: Don't use BASE_URL with required/included files. Use something like `__DIR__`  or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead.

Comment: It makes no sense to pass a URL to `require`. Pass the path of your file on the server's disk.

Comment: I change the $BASE_URL by path $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and that works, but now , i have another problem, i can't use the functions of function.php and I don't know why but i can use the command echo in the file function.php and it work. So the link is good but i can't use the function of the file.

Comment: Without more information, we cannot tell you why you can't use the functions.

Comment: What information you need?

Comment: Any errors, as well as the code.

Comment: my error is on the website when i go in the console, I have : `GET https://#####/views/me.php 500`
On each page but the index works

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: My bad, I miss in my function to change `$BASE_URL ` to `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` ^^'

Comment: That's a very old strategy to build a site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When including component files in PHP, you should be using **file paths**, not URLs. For example, we can use relative file paths to include the header in `pageOther1.php`, which should be like this.

```
require "../../../assets/components/header.php";
// OR
require __DIR__ . "/../../assets/components/header.php";
```

To make things more efficient, especially if you are going to include multiple components and have different levels of nested views, you could define the header and footer paths (and include any other global scripts like `functions.php`) in a PHP file (e.g. `initialize.php` or `config.php`) on the **root directory** of your app. That way you only need to require `initialize.php` and include the components you want using PHP constants.

#### Here's a more efficient approach

Define the component paths as a constant in a PHP file (e.g. `initialize.php`) on the root directory

```
define("APP_PATH", dirname(__FILE__)); // The main project directory
define("HEADER", "APP_PATH" . "/assets/components/header.php"); // Path to header.php
define("FOOTER", "APP_PATH" . "/assets/components/footer.php"); // Path to footer.php

// You could also include your global scripts here and don't have to include it on each view page
require "APP_PATH" . "/path_to_global_script.php";
```

Then include the components and scripts in a view. An example with `pageOther1.php` will be:

```
require "../../../initialize.php"; // Path to the file which defines the constants
require HEADER;
// Page content
require FOOTER;
```

You can easily extend this for multiple components and function scripts.